# Evaluate the integral $\int_0^\infty\frac{x^a\ln{x}}{x+b} \, dx$

Tags: integration, complex-integration

Integrate $\dfrac{x^a\ln{x}}{x+b}$ from 0 to infinity where $b > 0$ and $-1 < a < 0 $

I'm having trouble deciding how to approach the problem! Thank you!

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1553522/integrate-int-0-infty-fracxa-lnxxbdx-by-the-method-of-residues

Answer (score 1):

This integral is the derivative of
$$ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^a}{x+b} \, dx $$
with respect to $a$. We can remove $b$ by setting $bu=x$, so $dx=b \, du$,
$$ b^{a}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{u^a}{1+u} \, du. $$
I evaluated this integral [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1220923/improper-integral-of-a-rational-function/1220962#1220962), so we have
$$ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^a}{x+b} \, dx = -b^{a} \pi \csc{\pi a}. $$
Now we differentiate this with respect to $a$, to obtain the answer
$$ b^a \pi \csc{\pi a} \left( \pi \cot{\pi a}-\log{b} \right). $$