# Integrate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^a\ln(x)}{(x+b)}dx$ by the method of residues

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

How to evaluate
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^a\ln(x)}{(x+b)}dx$$
where $b > 0$ and $-1 < a < 0$ using the method of residues, but I have done only problems of simple poles, but this is much more than that. I am stuck on this problem, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: strange, this questions pops up very frequently the last days...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1553048/tricky-residue-integration

Comment: @tired - can you please get me the answer to that here.

Comment: try to use my hint here:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1550491/residue-integration-help